# Create background quadrants in scatterplot

Tags: highcharts

I want to create background quadrants like shown here in the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/vo97dry6/

But unlike the fiddle above my max/min range is [0-1 ] so i am getting overlapping quadrants.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/25d6g398/

```
xAxis: {

    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    tickInterval: 0.5,
    tickLength: 0,
    minorTickLength: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    showLastLabel: true,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    lineColor: '#ccc',
    lineWidth: 1,

},
yAxis: {

    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    tickInterval: 0.5,
    tickLength: 3,
    minorTickLength: 0,
    lineColor: '#ccc',
    lineWidth: 1,

},
series: [
   { // next four series are for color
             type: 'area',
             fillOpacity: 0.1,
             data: [[0.5,1.1], [-0.1, 1.1]],
             lineWidth: 0
         },
         {
             type: 'area',
             fillOpacity: 0.1,
             data: [[0.5, 1.1], [1.1, 1.1]],
             lineWidth: 0
         },
         {
             type: 'area',
             fillOpacity: 0.1,
             data: [[-0.1, 0.5], [1.1, 0.5]],
             lineWidth: 0
         },
         {
             type: 'area',
             fillOpacity: 0.1,
             data: [[-0.1, 0.5], [1.1, 0.5]],
             lineWidth: 0
         }
   ]
```

1. How an i hack to create neat background quadrants
2. How can I add quadrant labels clicking on which should perform some function (for example do a drilldown on that quadrant)
3. How can i make my axis to center at 0.5,0.5 instead of 0,0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aejtf16o/. To add labels you can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: I said my data points are [0,1] not [-1,1] .. this will not work on [0,1], I want to center at 50% i.e. (0.5,0.5)

Comment: @WojciechChmiel could you please correct your solution .. Thanks

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0rv8641f/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thank you very much .. I forgot that i could add 4 points instead of just 1 .. that was a trivial solution .. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Could I add this as an answer and you will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use 4 points instead of 2:

```
series: [{
  type: 'area',
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  data: [
    [0.5, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5]
  ],
  lineWidth: 0
}, {
  type: 'area',
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  data: [
    [0, 0],
    [0.5, 0],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0, 0.5]
  ],
  lineWidth: 0
}, {
  type: 'area',
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  data: [
    [0, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 1],
    [0, 1]
  ],
  lineWidth: 0
}, {
  type: 'area',
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  data: [
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [1, 0.5],
    [1, 1],
    [0.5, 1]
  ],
  lineWidth: 0
}]
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0rv8641f/